# Two way SSL certificates for API Calls

Tags: spring-mvc, ssl-certificate, okhttp, keystore, spring5

I have a public certificate, SSL client private certificate available in my local. I am not sure how to use these certificates and make API calls (Using Two-way SSL) in my Spring-MVC code (using Keystore/truststore).

Could someone help with a java example by using these certificates to call a REST API.

Certificates that i have are:

1. public.cer
2. sslclient.private
3. private.passphrase

Comment: Step 1 would be to repackage the certificates into two PKCS12 files so that they’re easily consumable from Java. Step 2 would be to add some examples of what you’ve tried to your question-m

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you. Just created a Keystore(.JKS) with the certificates and used the fingerprint while calling REST API and all worked fine.